# Change CSS, based on the current user logged in (NodeJS, SocketIO, ChatApp)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

So I'm trying to build a simple chat application. And when you are log in, the current user's message should always be on the right side and the other user's message on the left side. What is the best way to approach this?

Currently, I have done it so that a `class` tag is assigned to the message and saved into the database itself. And using `socket.io` whenever a new user connects, I have a function which checks with the user who logged in and then changes the `class` on the MongoDB database, which then changes it on the client-side through the js. But when you have 2 users logged in, and then refresh, it kinda goes haywire. As it changes the `class` on the other users as well.

The chat is available here: https://theuglychatbox.herokuapp.com/

It's hard to explain in words but here is a picture:

[image: chat screen]

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongooes = require('mongoose');
const UserDB = require('./models/UserDB');
const ChatDB = require('./models/ChatDB');
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use('/static', express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
dotenv.config();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/chat/login');
}); 

app.use('/chat', require('./routes/chatRoutes'));

io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    var session = socket.request.session;
    console.log('A user has connected');
    socket.on('Login', (user, clientID) => {
        var CurrUserQ = {sender: user};
        var currentUser = {class: "current-user-message"};
        var otherUser = {class: "other-user-message"};
        ChatDB.find({}, (err, chat) => {
            var senders = [];   
            var sendersID = [];
            for (let x=0; x < chat.length; x++){
                senders.push(chat[x].sender);
                sendersID.push(chat[x].id);
            };
            for (let xi=0; xi < senders.length; xi++){
                if(senders[xi] != user){
                    ChatDB.findByIdAndUpdate(sendersID[xi], otherUser, err =>{
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                };
            };
            ChatDB.find(CurrUserQ, (err, result) => {
                var ids = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    ids.push(result[i].id);
                };
                for (let ii = 0; ii < ids.length; ii++) {
                    ChatDB.findByIdAndUpdate(ids[ii], currentUser, err => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                            //ChatDB.findByIdAndDelete(ids[ii], (err, chat) => {
                            //    console.log('Deleted')
                            //}); for deletion
                };
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Failed" + err);
                };
            });
        });
        console.log(session);
        console.log('Logged in by ' + user);
        io.sockets.emit('LoggedIN', {user: user, clientID: clientID});
        console.log('WHY')
    });
    socket.on('userName', (name) =>{
        socket.on('message', (msg, userSP, clientID) => { //configure userSP in ejs code...
            const Chat = new ChatDB({
                message: msg,
                sender: userSP,
                seen: false,
                class: 'current-user-message'
            });
            try {
                Chat.save();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            };
            io.sockets.emit('msgCurrUser', {msg: msg, userSP: userSP, clientID: clientID});
            //socket.emit('msgCurrUser', {msg: msg, userSP: userSP, cls: 'current-user-message'});
            //socket.broadcast.emit('msgCurrUser', {msg: msg, userSP: userSP, cls: 'other-user-message'}); 
        });
    });
});

mongooes.set("useFindAndModify", false); // To avoid error

mongooes.connect(process.env.DB_connect, {useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
    console.log('Connected to Database');
    http.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
    });
});
```

Here is my html for the where the ejs is used:

```
<h2>Welcome <span id='name'><%= name %></span></h2>
<% chat.forEach(messages => { %>
 <div class="chat">
  <h6 class=<%= messages.class %>><%= messages.sender %></h6>
   <div id=<%= messages.class %>>
     <h4><%= messages.message %></h4>
   </div>
 </div>
<% }); %>
```

^^here the <% name %> is coming from the login page, and is sent through the redirected url. As such: `res.redirect('/chat/home?valid=' + userName)`;, and `username` is collected thru `req.body.username` on login page.

And finally here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function scrollSmoothToBottom (id) {
                var div = document.getElementById(id);
                $('#' + id).animate({scrollTop: div.scrollHeight}, '2');
                return [div.scrollHeight, div.clientHeight];
            };
            $(function(){
                
                var socket = io(); 
                var clientSD;
                var $msgs = $(".message-input");
                var $name = $('#name');
                $("form").submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault(); //prevents default reload
                    clientSD = socket.id;
                    socket.emit("message", $msgs.val(), $name.text(), clientSD); //gets the value of the specifc id and then sends it to the calling message
                    $msgs.val(''); //resets the input box
                    return false;
                });
                socket.on('connect', function(){
                    scrollSmoothToBottom('mainchat');
                    socket.emit('userName', $name.text());
                });
                socket.on('msgCurrUser', function(data) {
                    scrollSmoothToBottom('mainchat');

                    var $chatCont = document.createElement('div');
                    var $heading = document.createElement('h6');
                    var $actChat = document.createElement('div');
                    var $msgh4 = document.createElement('h4');

                    $chatCont.className = "chat";
                    $heading.append(data.userSP);

                    if(clientSD === data.clientID) {
                        $actChat.setAttribute("id", "current-user-message");
                        $heading.className = "current-user-message";
                    } else{
                        $actChat.setAttribute("id", "other-user-message");
                        $heading.className = "other-user-message";
                    }

                    $msgh4.append(data.msg);
                    $('.chatbox').append($chatCont); 
                    $chatCont.append($heading);
                    $chatCont.append($actChat);
                    $actChat.append($msgh4);
                });
                //added // to stop this event!!!
                socket.on('LoggedIN//', function(data) {
                    console.log(data.user);
                    var $name = $('#name');
                    $name.append(data.user);
                })
            });
        </script>
```

This is all the relevant part of my code, it is not the most effective/correct way but I'm just learning and any help is appreciated. Sorry if it's not good...thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to do this without changing much. So instead of the whole `change-id` function running in the `socket.on('Login'...`, I added some ajax code on the front-end in my `.js`. This function then also looks at the database entries and identifies if the `currenetUser` and `sender` match. As a result, then adds some HTML. It then removes the need for the `ejs` elements.

NOTE: This is a bit slower than rendering a ejs template directly.

Not explained well, but if you have any questions feel free to ask. And if there's a better solution plz let me know.

The ajax code in the `.js` file:

```
$(function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: '/chat/getData',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    let htmlstr = "";
                    console.log('success', data);
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if(data[i].sender == $name.text()) {
                            console.log('CurrUser')
                            htmlstr += '<div class="chat"> \
                                            <h6 id="sender" class="current-user-message">' + data[i].sender + '</h6> \
                                            <div id="current-user-message"> \
                                                <h4>' + data[i].message + '</h4> \
                                            </div> \
                                        </div>'
                            $('#chatbox').html(htmlstr);         
                        } else {
                            htmlstr += '<div class="chat"> \
                                            <h6 id="sender" class="other-user-message">' + data[i].sender + '</h6> \
                                            <div id="other-user-message"> \
                                                <h4>' + data[i].message + '</h4> \
                                            </div> \
                                        </div>'
                            $('#chatbox').html(htmlstr);  
                        }
                    };

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('error', errorThrown);
                }
                });
            });
```